# Selenium Webdriver Black Screenshot PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, cucumber

Testing a site using Cucumber and Selenium. In my hooks.js file I have the following:

```
driver.get("https://localhost:8000/");

sleep(2000);

TakeScreenshot('./test_artifacts/img/', 'Load Success', driver);

var btn = this.driver.wait(selenium.until.elementLocated(By.css('#app > div > div > div.col-xs-6.textColumn > button'), seleniumTimeOut));

TakeScreenshot('./test_artifacts/img/', 'Load Success', driver);

this.driver.sleep(3000);
```

The objective here is to successfully load the page and to take a screenshot of it. The website is running off of localhost. The problem occurs when a screenshot is taken. No matter how long I get driver to sleep I get a black screenshot, indicating to me that the website is not 'building' in time (to use what may be an incorrect term, given the circumstances). I then get this error:

```
Waiting for element to be located By(css selector, #app > div > div > div.col-xs-6.textColumn > button)
Wait timed out after 20112ms
```

If I change the URL to https://google.com/ I get a screenshot of the site, no problem. Any ideas what is happening here? Is my above hypothesis correct?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been a certification problem. The tests would run on http but when localhost was using https the tests would fail. 
I worked around it by adding the following to this.BeforeFreature in my hooks.js file:

```
this.driver = new selenium.Builder()
      .withCapabilities({'phantomjs.cli.args': ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true']})
      .forBrowser('phantomjs')
      .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to wait until some other elements to be available. Use xpath locator instead CSS. Is your machine behind proxy? if means please add the phantom browser in behind the proxy.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(browser){
    browser.createPage(function(page){

    browser.setProxy('98.239.198.83','21320','http', null, null, function(){

    page.open(
        'http://example.com/req.php', function() {

         });});});});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change the driver to chrome driver and see what is script is doing after changing the URL. The different environment some time have different id's and XPath which affect the script. so before moving to phantomjs directly first check the behaviour of your script with common drivers like chrome or firefox.

I have gone through the same scenario and I have experienced the same situation. It's a silly mistake which was wasted my half of the day :p

Hope it will help you :)